# How to identify what user agents my apps use in iOS

Tags: ios, user-agent

I have an iPad2 running iOS 8.1. I'm trying to find the user agents that apps use on it (example Facebook app). Packet captures via tcpdump of Linux modem on client side NIC shows most apps not using http. Impossible / impractical to identify?

Comment: You're not going to be able to get "User-Agent" (an HTTP header) from a protocol that isn't HTTP. Opening a socket and establishing a connection to a remote server does not require HTTP.

Comment: I'm assuming by "not using http" he means "using HTTPS" (since that's what most apps use.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a web debugging proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). [Here's configuration information](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/). You'll be able to see SSL-encrypted traffic if you install [the Charles SSL Certificate](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/). (If uses SSL Pinning, you'll only be able to see the headers.)

For example, Facebook's iOS User-Agent when connecting to api.facebook.com is:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12B411 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/16.0.0.13.22;FBBV/4697910;FBDV/iPhone7,2;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/8.1;FBSS/2; FBCR/Verizon;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/5]